# Performing certain operations at certain time on the web server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks

In my web application (ASP.NET MVC), I need to do a certain function (refresh a table with data) every Sunday at 12:00 am.

How can I do that?

We meet it everywhere. For example Google Adsense's stats update only every hour or so. How can you set up this interval update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a scheduled task on the server to call a web-page that will update the table.

Go read **[this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163821.aspx)**.